# How to properly translate HttpExceptions in the Frontend with Angular?

Tags: python, angular, translation, fastapi, httpexception

We have a complex business logic where we raise several [HTTPExceptions](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/) with FastAPI if an error occurs. When we raise an exception we define a status code and a detail error message. The problem is that this error message is in english but our application has a german interface and we would like to display this error message translated to german in a [toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr).

Unfortunately FastAPI doesn't describe what to do if you want to display the detail error message in another language so I was wondering what the best way would be to show a translated error message when we raise said HttpExceptions.

A HTTPException with FastAPI looks somewhat like this:

```
raise HTTPException(
    status_code=HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail=PERMISSION_ERROR
)
```

We can additionally maybe add some custom headers but that's basically it.

Comment: You can use pydantic-i18n: https://pydantic-i18n.boardpack.org/

Comment: This looks promising, thank you very much!

Comment: Have you looked into a possible use of [interceptors](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)?

Comment: I'm not sure if your problem lies in catching the error before it is being displayed, or the translating itself. There are libraries like [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) to help with this.